# Magento 2.1 - On reindex start event

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer, indexing

I am looking for an observer event that is triggered when any re-index starts.

I want to create an observer that sends out an email whenever an index has been initiated for re-indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the `indexer_state_save_before` event which is one of the standard events that get fired [before a model gets saved in the DB](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php#L683).

This event should be triggered when a new entry is stored in the `indexer_state` table which happens every time an indexer runs.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you any event before the indexer starts working, but this event fires just after the reindexer has finished:

`clean_cache_after_reindex`